# Angular / Firestore - Fetching the ID created by the 'add' method to use in a router navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- FireStore

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Create a new item using the 'add' method
- Navigate to a URL that includes the new ID generated by the 'add' method

**Issues**

- I can create a new item fine
- I don't know how to obtain the ID of the newly created item
- I keep ending up with the ID of the page i'm on

**Questions**

- How do I get the ID of a new item the moment I've created a new item and use that in a router link?

**Component TS**

As you can see, in my router, I have put a placeholder of 'newId'. This is the part I want to be the ID of the item that's just been created by the 'Add' part.

```js
  addTemplateProject() {

    var album_title = new Date();

    const newAlbum: any = { project_title }

    this.albumCollection.add(newAlbum);

    this.router.navigate(['folders', this.folderId, 'albums', newId, 'edit']);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) states:

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
db.collection("cities").add({
    name: "Tokyo",
    country: "Japan"
})
.then(function(docRef) {
    console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
});
```

You can get the reference on succesful add. In your case:

```
this.albumCollection.add(newAlbum).then(function(ref) {console.log(ref.id});
```

Comment: Yup, I had just found that. Stupidly didn't check the docs for Firestore. Was just looking at AngularFire for firestore stuff... Thanks Carsten.